# ListView on slug request

Tags: python, django, listview, slug

My URL

```
/tags/{slug}
```

points to this view:

```
class TagsDetailList(request, ListView):
    queryset = Link.objects.filter(tags__name__in=['request.slug'])
    template_name = "links/tags_detail_list.html"
```

So i have the request.slug object in the url.
Now i want to make a ListView that filters Link.objects by request.slug and respond to given template with the queried result.

All works but no queries are given on my template.

response template is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Tags Detail List</h2>
    <ul>
        {% if link in object_list %}
            {% for link in object_list %}            
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'tag_detail' slug=link.slug %}">{{ link.title }}</a>
                </li>           
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
                <p> Error: No Links in queryset! </p>
        {% endif %}
    <ul>
{% endblock %}
```

i dont get some elements, only the error message. its something bad on the request on my view.
who can help me and give me a hint how i can retrieve the request slug on my view?

EDIT:

nice solutions. i learned the way kwargs work(a small part).
But on the template i get still the error for no queryset. Tried both answers and also changed a bit but never really worked. Any hint what cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done here doesn't make sense: you're just asking for tags whose names are in the list consisting of the literal text " request.slug".

You need to override `get_queryset` so that it queries on the actual value of the slug, which is in `self.kwargs`.

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return  Link.objects.filter(tags__name=self.kwargs ['slug'])
```

Also, I don't know what that if statement is doing in your template, but you haven't defined "link" do it will never evaluate to true, so no links will show.

Answer (score 4):

If your `urls` pattern something like this:

```
r'^list/(?P<slug>[\w,\*]+)?$'
```

So in the `views` should be:

```
class TagsDetailList(ListView):
    model = Link
    template_name = "links/tags_detail_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        if self.kwargs.get('slug'):
            qs = qs.filter(tags__name=self.kwargs['slug'])

        return qs
```

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering

Comment: i tried this way but the template show me the Error: No Links.      {% if link in object_list %} - no link in object-list.                some way to check on the view if slug has passed?

Comment: 1) so you have no objects in your queryset after those filter wrap all code by {% if object_list %} {% endif %}

Comment: 2) `slug` will be passed anyway, because it required by `urls` pattern, or urls resolver will not map (associate) request url to your view

Comment: 3) if you want make `slug` unnecessary - change your url pattern `r'^list/(?P<slug>[\w,\*]+)?$'`

Comment: okay. thanks. no result anyway. seems like the passed slug f.ex. 'suche' get queried like this *WHERE "taggit_tag"."name" IN (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' - PARAMS = (u'7', u"'s'", u"'u'", u"'c'", u"'h'", u"'e'")*  -> no prob if i pass slug value on view.

Comment: qs.filter(tags__name=self.kwargs.get('slug'))

Comment: :) I've refactored answer, - second time simply use `self.kwargs['slug']` because we already know that we have `slug` kwarg

Comment: @dukebody Thanks for the link! It helped really but really a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help, but it works for me in Django 2+:

Your `urls.py`:

```
...
path('tags/<slug>/', TagsDetailList.as_view(), name='tags_detail'),
...
```

Your `views.py`:

```
...
class TagsDetailList(ListView):
    model = Link
    template_name = 'links/tags_detail_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Link.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
...
```